# Linux: how to know which processes are pinned to which core?

Tags: linux, cpu, process-management, high-performance

Is there a way to know which cores currently have a process pinned
to them?

Even processes run by other users should be listed in the output.

Or, is it possible to try pinning a process to a core but
fail in case the required core already has a process pinned to it?

PS: processes of interest must have bin pinned to the given cores, not just
currently running on the given core

PS: this is not a duplicate, the other question is on how to ensure exclusive use of one CPU by one process. Here we are asking how to detect that a process was pinned to a given core (i.e. cpuset was used, not how to use it).

Comment: see the `taskset` command

Comment: A somewhat controversial part of our system is that questions don’t have to be the same question to be duplicates.  All that is required is that the answer to question ***B*** is present in question ***A***’s thread.  If you have fully read the answer to [How to ensure exclusive CPU availability for a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326579/23408) and tried everything that looks relevant to your question, say *that*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to myself:
hwloc-bind from Linux (and homebrew for Macs) package hwloc.
Cf. https://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/tutorials/20130115-ComPAS-hwloc-tutorial.pdf for some doc.

Answer (score 23):

Under normal circumstances Linux processes are not explicitly pinned to a given core, there's typically no reason to do that, but is possible.

You can manage process affinity using `taskset` or view which process runs on which CPU in the present instant using ps with the field 'psr'.

Check current CPU affinity of process 27395:

```
$ ps -o psr 27395
PSR
  6
```

Check affinity list of process 27395:

```
$ taskset -pc 27395
pid 27395's current affinity list: 0-7
```

Set affinity of process 27395 to CPU 3

```
$ taskset -pc 3 27395
pid 27395's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 27395's new affinity list: 3
```

Check current CPU affinity of process 27395:

```
$ ps -o psr 27395
PSR
  3
```

To check if any process is pinned to any CPU, you can loop through your process identifiers and run `taskset -p` against them:

```
$ for pid in $(ps -a -o pid=); do taskset -pc $pid 2>/dev/null; done
pid 1803's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 1812's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 1986's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2027's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2075's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2083's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2122's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2180's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2269's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2289's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2291's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2295's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2300's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 2302's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 3872's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 4339's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 7301's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 7302's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 7309's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 13972's current affinity list: 0-7
```

Comment: "there is just no reason to do that". Here is one reason: improve the performance of parallel programs.

Comment: Aye, I've had to pin procs to a given CPU on occasion. Such as to reduce the context switching when multiple procs are competing for CPU time. Or to avoid dealing with NUMA.

Comment: I did say 'under normal circumstances'. Of course if you have a use case for it, then there's the solution :-) "Improve the performance of parallel programs" is a very generic goal. This is what the scheduler does and it does a pretty good job at it. You need to be very skilled or have a very specific situation to do better yourself. But you don't need to trust me, just give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

First open terminal and do `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to list all cores. Core 0 = 1st core, Core 1 = 2nd core...

Then

```
CORENUM=0
ps -e -o pid,psr,cpu,cmd | grep -E  "^[[:space:]][[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+${CORENUM}"
```

to see what has core 1 (replace 0 in `CORENUM=` with desired core number) assigned to it.

Comment: That `ps` format does nothing on my system. It certainly doesn't list which CPUs a process is pinned to. My `ps` man page doesn't even have a `cpu` field documented (it has `%cpu`, but not `cpu`).

Comment: @Patrick Which distro do you have?

Comment: root@localhost:~# CORENUM=0; ps -e -o pid,psr,cpu,cmd | grep -E  "^[[:space:]][[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+${CORENUM}"
 1008   0   - /usr/lib/colord/colord
 1207   0   - /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
 1666   0   - gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]
 1669   0   - /lib/systemd/systemd --user
 1670   0   - (sd-pam)
 1681   0   - /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
 1687   0   - /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script /usr/bin/startlxde
 1689   0   - /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/0/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3

Comment: There's more, but StackExchange says it's too long to paste it all. So i shortened it...

Comment: `processes of interest must have bin pinned to the given cores, not just currently running on the given core`

Answer (score 2):

#### Currently assigned vCPU

You can use the `-F` switch to `ps` to see which core (vCPU) a process is currently running on. The PSR column indicates which:

```
$ man ps
...
       psr         PSR       processor that process is currently assigned to.
...
```

For eg:

```
$ ps -Fae | head
UID         PID   PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root          1      0  0 211946 655576 13 Oct17 ?       00:51:28 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 14
root          2      0  0     0     0  16 Oct17 ?        00:00:02 [kthreadd]
root          6      2  0     0     0   0 Oct17 ?        00:50:36 [ksoftirqd/0]
root          7      2  0     0     0   0 Oct17 ?        00:02:04 [migration/0]
root          8      2  0     0     0   0 Oct17 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
root          9      2  0     0     0   0 Oct17 ?        02:02:22 [rcu_sched]
root         10      2  0     0     0   5 Oct17 ?        00:00:00 [lru-add-drain]
root         11      2  0     0     0   0 Oct17 ?        00:00:10 [watchdog/0]
root         12      2  0     0     0   1 Oct17 ?        00:00:09 [watchdog/1]
```

Something similar can be done using `top` and selecting the `P` field by adding it via <kbd>f</kbd>.

> 12. P  --  Last used CPU (SMP)
>
> A number representing the last used processor.  In a true SMP environment this    will likely  change frequently  since the kernel intentionally uses weak affinity. 
>   Also, the very act of running top may break this weak affinity and
>   cause more processes to change CPUs more often (because of the extra demand for 
>   cpu time).

For e.g.:

```
Tasks: 623 total,   3 running, 620 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.7 us, 11.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.2 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 26397158+total, 18521476+free, 35842280 used, 42914536 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 22101484+avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                        P
  2061 root      20   0  414648  15104   9068 S  38.6  0.0   2:06.82 sssd_be                                        2
 58915 root      20   0 2366608 130232  12288 S  29.5  0.0 478:46.62 filebeat                                      15
  4851 root      20   0 3740952 125192  18412 S  15.9  0.0   2944:25 metricbeat                                     4
104253 1007430+  20   0   16.0t   2.0g   1.6g S  13.6  0.8 138:59.97 java                                           3
  7617 root      20   0 5160288 399292  49324 S  11.4  0.2  12066:35 hyperkube                                      5
100062 1002840+  20   0   52440  17892   3800 R  11.4  0.0   0:00.34 cub                                            8
100202 smingol+  20   0  172872   2984   1712 R  11.4  0.0   0:00.09 top                                            8
112115 1007680+  20   0 5747228   1.2g  23428 S  11.4  0.5   1457:10 java                                          11
  2645 root      20   0 5425332 253544  18132 S   9.1  0.1   4549:50 dockerd-current                               12
```

#### CPU Affinity

If you're more interested in any affinity a process may have for a particular vCPU you can use `taskset` for that. Below we can see a process (`sleep`) which has been affinitized to specific vCPUs in the 1st example and allowed to run on any in the 2nd:

```
$ taskset -c 0,2,4,6 sleep 10000 &
[1] 119472
$ taskset -cp 119472
pid 119472's current affinity list: 0,2,4,6

$ sleep 10001  &
[2] 85436
$ taskset -cp 85436
pid 85436's current affinity list: 0-71
```

To see all processes on a box:

```
$ ps -ae -o pid= | xargs -n 1 taskset -cp
pid 116921's current affinity list: 47
pid 117171's current affinity list: 0-71
pid 117189's current affinity list: 0-71
pid 117248's current affinity list: 36
pid 117665's current affinity list: 0-71
pid 117681's current affinity list: 10
pid 118635's current affinity list: 0-71
pid 118665's current affinity list: 0-71
pid 118873's current affinity list: 44
pid 119472's current affinity list: 0,2,4,6
...
```

#### References

- [How can I see which CPU core a thread is running in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032372/how-can-i-see-which-cpu-core-a-thread-is-running-in)
- [Managing Process Affinity in Linux](https://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html)