# How do I flag a process to avoid hyperthreading (SMT)?

Tags: linux, scheduling, priority, hyperthreading

Suppose I have an 18 core CPU with SMT enabled, and there are 18 long runnning processes, all using ~100% of a thread. If I start a 19th process, the kernel will schedule it to run on one of the cores, as a hypersibling of one of the 18 other processes.

If that 19th process is something I want to have complete faster without interrupting the first 18, I would want to ask the kernel to "give that one an entire core", and push one of the rest to be a hypersibling.

In other words, I want to flag the 19th process to never be scheduled on a thread which has a hypersibling in use by another process.

Using nice -20 does not seem to work for this purpose.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326579/how-to-ensure-exclusive-cpu-availability-for-a-running-process/326585

Comment: FYI, four years later, the answer given in the comment by @RuiFRibeiro - [isolcpus](https://www.codeblueprint.co.uk/2019/10/08/isolcpus-is-deprecated-kinda.html) - is now deprecated. That link recommends using `cgroups` to do it, which is what containers are based on.